# Convert factors to numbers in a categorical data quickly

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a big categorical data frame like

```
col1     col2     col3
abcd     rweff    3433534
gfds     erwq     trdfs
abcd     erwq     trdfs
abcd     rweff    3433534
```

......

I want to replace all these complicated categories to simple numbers, something like this

```
col1     col2     col3
1          2        1
2          1        2
1          1        2
1          2        1
```

......

How do I quickly achieve it in R?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the columns are of 'factor' class

```
df1[] <- lapply(df1, as.numeric)
df1
#  col1 col2 col3
#1    1    2    1
#2    2    1    2
#3    1    1    2
#4    1    2    1
```

If the columns are 'character' class, then convert to 'factor' and use `as.numeric`

```
 df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) as.numeric(factor(x)))
```

These are similar options using `dplyr` or `data.table`.  It may be faster (haven't benchmarked)

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- mutate_each(df1, funs(as.numeric(.)))
```

If you use `%<>%` from `magrittr`, can avoid assigning to a new object or the existing one.

```
library(magrittr)
df1 %<>% 
      mutate_each(funs(as.numeric(.)))
```

Or

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, lapply(.SD, as.numeric)]
```

Or a bit more efficient method with `set` as it modifies columns by reference and the overhead of  `[.data.table` is avoided

```
 setDT(df1)
 for(j in 1:ncol(df1)){
  set(df1, i=NULL, j=j, value= as.numeric(df1[[j]]))
 }
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(col1 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L),
.Label =     c("abcd", 
"gfds"), class = "factor"), col2 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 2L
), .Label = c("erwq", "rweff"), class = "factor"),
col3 = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("3433534", "trdfs"), class = "factor")),
.Names = c("col1", 
"col2", "col3"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```